# Prevent composer from installing local jquery/jqueryui when using a CDN

Tags: composer-php

I've always used a local copy of jQuery and jQuery UI in my app, and have managed that via composer.

I've decided to switch to Google's CDN as circumstances have changed, so I removed both packages (`components/jquery` and `components/jqueryui`) from my list of requirements, thinking that would be it, but I forgot that a few of the other packages I still use require these packages, and so it just automatically re-installed the latest versions.

If I'm using Google's CDN to supply jQuery and jQuery UI, how do I prevent composer from installing local copies?

Comment: @yivi it's a requirement of one of the 3rd party packages, if not most of them. My question is how to prevent a local copy from being installed when I'm already including it manually from the CDN.

Comment: That's... unusual, at least. Not many composer packages would declare a javascript dependency. What package exactly is installing the jquery files?

Comment: @yivi it's a large project so there are 20+ package requirements from me, some of which are very large projects like ACE, CKeditor, lightview, jcrop, etc. as well as a number of bootstrap packages, symphony stuff (not using directly, but the requirements are there) with about 50-60 extended packages overall.

Comment: @yivi the packages are "components/jquery" and "components/jqueryui", I was just curious if there was a way to prevent them since they're redundant in our case and it just adds complexity where there doesn't need to be any. If there's no mechanism for it, so be it, but it was worth asking to save the hassle, thought it would be a more common issue than apparently it is.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Composer, but does not contain any such code? Usually, jQuery should not be installed using Composer, neither does Composer use any kind of CDN

Comment: @NicoHaase There isn't really any code required. And the OP mentioned that they installed these libraries with composer, and the name of the packages in comments (I've added the clarification, provided in comments, via an edit).  The question does not require additional details nor clarity.

Comment: @yivi I'd like to understand how jQuery was installed through Composer in the first place. If this is part of any other dependency, simply removing it might not be a good idea (as the other dependency is expecting it to be in the vendor folder). If it was not installed through any other dependency, uninstalling it like any other package should be sufficient

Comment: @Nico the question makes it clear: the packages `components/jquery` and `components/jqueryui` were installed by other dependencies, and the OP wants to prevent their installation. It's the same thing as for example what you do to avoid installation of symfony polyfills.

Comment: @NicoHaase After some more digging I started to find where the requirements are, these two required the `components/jquery`:  `silviomoreto/bootstrap-select`, `vakata/jstree`. Haven't found the jqueryui one yet, but you get the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent installing a particular package, because you know it's already provided somehow else by your project or other dependency Composer does not know about; what you need to do is use the `replace` key.

For example, to tell composer "do not download and install `components/jquery` and `components/jqueryui`, you'd do:

```json
{

   "replace": {
     "components/jquery": "*",
     "components/jqueryui": "*",
   }
}
```

This will prevent composer from downloading these packages, because you are effectively saying "my project already provides these packages".

Note, this simply will avoid downloading the package files. If some other dependency actually looks for the files provided by these packages, your application might hit trouble.

Comment: Easy solution, exactly what I was hoping for, thanks @yivi.